# Trying to figure out how to use the right element

Tags: jquery

I'm currently trying to iterate threw multiple products on my screen where I can add more as needed.  I have a Jquery function that calls my database to retrieve that information using JSON.

```
function FillProductbyupc(elem) {
        var $elem = $(elem),
            upcCode = $elem.data('upc');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Case/GetData/',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: "upc=" + upcCode,
            success: function (cics) {
                $elem.find(".corpitemcode").empty().append(
                    $elem.find('.corpitemcode').val(cics.CorpItemCode));
                $elem.find(".itemdesc").append(
                    $elem.find('.itemdesc').val(cics.ItemDsc));

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("UPC does not exist");
            }
        });
    }
    $(function () {

        $('.products').on('blur', '[data-upc]', function (e) {
            FillProductbyupc(this);
        });
    });
```

here is the code from the page where it is called

```
  <div class="col-md-12">

              @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Products)

        <p>

            @Html.AddLink("Add More Products", ".products", ".product", "Products", typeof(MSC.Models.Product))
        </p>
    </div>
```

and lastly here is my product class.

```
<div class="products">

    <div class="product">

        <p>
            <label>Product</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UPC, null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.UPC), data_upc = "5440001504" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PLU, null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.PLU) })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CorpItemCode, null, new { @class = "form-control corpitemcode", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CorpItemCode) })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ItemDsc, null, new { @class = "form-control itemdesc", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.ItemDsc) })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LaneNumber, null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.LaneNumber) })

            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DeleteProduct, new { @class = "mark-for-delete" })
            @Html.RemoveLink("Remove", "div.product", "input.mark-for-delete")

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My lines inside the success function:

```
 $(".corpitemcode").append(
    $elem.find('.corpitemcode').val(cics.CorpItemCode));
 $(".itemdesc").append(
    $elem.find('.itemdesc').val(cics.ItemDsc));
```

and I've also tried

```
 $elem.find('.corpitemcode').val(cics.CorpItemCode);
  $elem.find('.itemdesc').val(cics.ItemDsc);
```

The problem I am having is that the call to my controller then my business layer is that it always passes the upc or corpitemcode from the first product.  I'm assuming because the #upc id is always going to be the first one.  But since this loops threw, is there an element I can use instead of the ID to have it target the correct product?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use something that can have multiple instances, and that's not the ID of an element. Usually for this sort of thing you'd use either a class or a data-something attribute. You could kill two birds with one stone. Assign a data-corpitemcode attribute with the corpitemattribute value in your view and you can use $('[data-corpitemcode]') to select it with jquery and then use the value of that data attribute when passing it to your action via AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Chris.  I'm still a little confused on what you mean to do with the " $('[data-corpitemcode]') ".  I'm still somewhat of a rookie with JQuery and I just don't understand how to differeniate between  the instances of that product class?

Comment: Afraid I'm on a mobile at the mo, so hard to post a proper response but I'll get something posted in the morning.

Comment: Thanks abunch for the help out.  I'll keep researching as well to make sure I'm on par with what you are explaining.

Comment: Hopefully this pen will show you what I mean.  I've moved the event handler logic to the JS rather than using onblur attribute, modified your JS slightly, and I've kind of mashed your view into the HTML part so you can see what you'd need to do to that.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpYpaL

Comment: Hey Chris - Thanks for the code pen example.  It's not hitting my Controller.  I also added a period in front of 'products' to show it as a class.  Also I noticed one of issues may be the 'data_upc' on the view and 'data-upc' in the controller?  Thanks again

Comment: Ah... I just saw the underscore gets converted.  I am still having some issues with it though : / .

Comment: It was a quote that was missing on the 'blur' that was throwing it off : / ... I've should have noticed that.  But I am hitting the controller with a hardcoded UPC and it is successfully getting the product information.  But it is not populating my textboxes.  I'm thinking I have something mixed up in the success function.

Comment: If you post code as it is now as an update, I'll take a look over it and see if I can spot the problem.

Comment: I just updated the code to how it currently is in my original post.  Thanks again

Comment: Ah. Think I can see what the problem is. Wasn't too sure what you were trying to do when I did the codepen. If you're just trying to populate those text boxes, you can lose the .empty.append() stuff and just use the calls to .val(value) on each textbox to populate their values.

Comment: In the debugger it always goes to the error function instead of the success function in FF when it hit this line. success: function (cics).  I've added the code to that function at the bottom of my original post.